# React Tabulator giving error which is not recognizable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I am new to react and react tabulator. I am getting an error which I am not understanding.

This is my react tabulator code:

```
render() {
    const options = {
      
      pagination: 'local',
      paginationSize: 5,
      layout: 'fitDataFill',
      
    };

    const ReportColumns = [
      {
        title: 'TDC',
        field: 'TDC',
        minWidth: 20,
        headerSort: false,
        headerFilter: 'input',
        headerFilterPlaceholder: 'search...',
      },
    ];

<ReactTabulator
          data={this.state.reportList}
          columns={ReportColumns}
          options={options}
          // rowClick={this.rowClick}
          id="reportGrid"
        />
```

I am getting reportList from this function: I am getting value in reportList from the backend and adding it in reportList in the form of an array and populating it

```
getTableValue = () => {
    this.setState({ dataLoading: true });

    axiosAPI.post('api/observation/GetTableValue').then(response => {
      var rows = [];

      console.log('values for response:' + JSON.stringify(response.data));

      for (var i in response.data) {
        var rowdata = response.data[i];
        var ID = ++i;

        rows.push({
          ID: ID,
          OrgUnit: rowdata.OrgUnit,
          TDC: rowdata.TDC,
          CustCode: rowdata.CustCode,
          CustName: rowdata.CustName,
          DestCode: rowdata.DestCode,
          EMV: rowdata.EMV,
          Service: rowdata.Service,
          SPCCode: rowdata.SPCCode,
          SPCode: rowdata.SPCode,
          Remarks: rowdata.Remarks,
          Stage: rowdata.Stage,
          Cost: rowdata.Cost,
          SAPUpdate: rowdata.SAPUpdate,
          Active: rowdata.Active,
          CreatedBy: rowdata.CreatedBy,
          CreatedOn: rowdata.CreatedOn,
          UpdatedBy: rowdata.UpdatedBy,
          UpdatedOn: rowdata.UpdatedOn,
        });
        //this.setState({ reportList: rows });
      }
      this.setState({ reportList: rows });

      this.setState({ dataLoading: false });
    });
  };
```

I am inititializing reportList as an array in the state as so:

reportList: [],

This is the error I am getting:

```
./node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator_esm.js 6792:93
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6792:93)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| function progress(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
|   var element = cell.getElement(),
>       max = typeof editorParams.max === "undefined" ? element.getElementsByTagName("div") 
 [0]?.getAttribute("max") || 100 : editorParams.max,
|       min = typeof editorParams.min === "undefined" ? element.getElementsByTagName("div") 
 [0]?.getAttribute("min") || 0 : editorParams.min,
|       percent = (max - min) / 100,
```

[image]

I am not understanding what the error is and hence not able to resolve. Please help me in understanding the error and resolving it. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `tabulator-tables`, a dependency of `react-tabulator`. The error message is telling you that it was unable to parse the module itself, which, unless you went in and edited it, is not your code.

I was able to reproduce the error locally by trying to install and run the [react-tabulator live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mwpy612xw). You can try the same by downloading the sandbox using the upper left hand menu:

[image: codesandbox export]

Unzip the downloaded file into a new directory and then run `yarn install; yarn start` or the `npm` equivalents if you prefer.

The error message you received is an accurate description of the problem. Indeed, using dummy values for `max` and `min` in `node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator_esm.js` fixes the issue (with loss of functionality, obviously):

```js
function progress(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams){
    var element = cell.getElement(),
    // max = typeof editorParams.max === "undefined" ? ( element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]?.getAttribute("max") || 100) : editorParams.max,
    max = 100,
    // min = typeof editorParams.min === "undefined" ? ( element.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]?.getAttribute("min") || 0) : editorParams.min,
    min = 0,
```

That said, I'm stumped as to what the breaking difference between our local environments and codesandbox are. I copied the live demo I referenced above verbatim, including `package.json`, so aside maybe from a different `node` version, there *shouldn't* be a difference, to the best of my knowledge. There's certainly nothing wrong with the line where `Unexpected token` is reported.

What I would recommend here is filing an issue against `react-tabulator` at their [repository](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues). Rather than referencing your code, which has a lot of unrelated stuff in it, report, as I did above, that you downloaded their live demo *verbatim*, and it didn't run on your machine with such and such error message. Reference this answer if you like. Hopefully they will have some clue that's eluding me.